# Drupal Commerce: How to get payment module settings?

Tags: 7, commerce

How to programmatically retrieve configuration of the specific payment module?

I tried

```
$settings = rules_config_load('commerce_payment_MODULE_NAME');
```

It returns very basic info (name, ID etc) and empty "settings" array.

Cant also get it directly from DB .

It is stored in serialized array that can not be fully processed with the `unserialize()` function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm using this:

```
$payment = commerce_payment_method_instance_load('foo|commerce_payment_foo');
```

where `foo` is the payment method string identifier.

The resulting array contains the `'settings'` index, with the data saved in the settings form.

---

In other words `foo|commerce_payment_foo` is instance id which consist `method_id|rule_name`.

The `method_id` can be found by executing `commerce_payment_methods()` and `rule_name` can be found in URL when editing Payment action (at `/admin/commerce/config/payment-methods`).

Comment: this is really helpful for me, are there a way to validate settings form?

Comment: Where can I get the payment method string identifier 'foo' and 'commerce_payment_foo'?