# How to inherit Payment Gateway configurations?

Tags: commerce, configuration, payment-gateways

I have a **main payment gateway** which I want to **configure**.
And **multiple other payment gateways** which I want to **inherit** the main gateway's configuration data.

I only have the **CommercePaymentGateway ID** (set in the annotation) of the main payment gateway and I want to get it's configuration **inside of the other payment gateways**.

I found [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9069/drupal-commerce-how-to-get-payment-module-settings) post, but the solution is for Drupal 7 and doesn't work in Drupal 8 and 9.

How could I achieve this? Is there a better way to inherit configurations?

Thank you for any input!

Comment: Are you configuring the payment gateway in the UI?  Is the configuration data you are referring to the settings that you input in the UI?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PatrickKenny Yes, the configuration data I am reffering to is the settings you input right after you create a payment gateway in the UI.